# How can I add UISwitch(toggle switch) to UIToolBar without using InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar, uiswitch

How can I add UISwitch(toggle switch) to UIToolBar without using InterfaceBuilder ?
It is not a system item, so I could not use

```
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton1:)];
```

How can I add the toggle switch  in same way ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`-initWithCustomView:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:) with your switch as that custom view.

Comment: But, I cannot set it to user enabled. Should I add code for it to be toggled when touched ?

Comment: @srikanth: I guess so. The view of the bar button item itself is also a button, which may hijack the touch. You can set the `target` and `action` properties of the bar button item though.

Comment: Sorry, for my slow learning. But, I saw this following method. It do not have target and action like remaining methods.
- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView;

Comment: Sorry, I did not check well. It is toggling. It is working. I need to to add selectors for on and off conditions. 
Thank you.

Comment: @srikanthrongali Have you tried binding to `UIControlEventsValueChanged`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in my swift app, where I had to switch between two different modes of display.

```
    let optionSwitch:UISwitch = UISwitch()

    let optionToolButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: optionSwitch);
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = optionToolButton
```